# Unable to locate div.class element in html using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests, html-parsing

I am trying to run the following BeautifulSoup code on https://apps.npr.org/best-books/#view=list&year=2022 to locate the book title of the books listed on this page. I am using the below code, which I have confirmed generally works a basic web scraper:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://apps.npr.org/best-books/#view=list&year=2022'

page = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

soup.find_all('div',{'class':'title'})
```

Which I would expect would yield a list of all the book titles. Instead, I am getting an empty list, which essentially means it is not finding the html I'm searching for.

For reference, an example of an html string that has the information I want (which can equivalently be found by inspecting the source of the page I linked above):

```
<div class="title">(Serious) New Cook: Recipes, Tips, and Techniques</div>
```

Any tips on how to troubleshoot this?

Comment: Data to that page is fetched from API - requests will not help you unless you directly call that api

Comment: Thank you for the comment - can you help me understand how you saw that the data was fetched from an api?

Comment: you go to the website with your browser, you open the devtools and navigate to network console and see all the requests the page does. API calls most often return JSON type ..

Answer (score 0):

Simply fecth the data from the api, you could find it in the dev tools of your browser, check the xhr tab:

```
import requests
requests.get('https://apps.npr.org/best-books/2022.json').json()
```

##### Output

```
[{'title': 'The School for Good Mothers: A Novel',
  'author': 'Jessamine Chan',
  'dimensions': {'width': 329, 'height': 500},
  'cover': '1982156120',
  'tags': ['sci fi, fantasy & speculative fiction',
   'book club ideas',
   'eye-opening reads',
   'family matters',
   'identity & culture',
   'the states we’re in',
   'staff picks',
   'the dark side'],
  'id': 1},
 {'title': 'Young Mungo',
  'author': 'Douglas Stuart',
  'dimensions': {'width': 336, 'height': 500},
  'cover': '0802159559',
  'tags': ['realistic fiction',
   'book club ideas',
   'family matters',
   'identity & culture',
   'love stories',
   'seriously great writing',
   'tales from around the world',
   'staff picks'],
  'id': 2},...]
```

Comment: This is very helpful thank you! Can you show where you were able to see that you needed to look at an api vs the html?

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely because the content is loaded using javascript. You could either fetch from the API like HedgeHog suggested or you could load the javascript in the page using a automated browser like selenium.